# Check if check box state has changed and submit button had been pressed at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

OK, so I have a table of checkboxes. Once my page loads, some of these check boxes may be checked and some may be unchecked. I need to sense a change in state in any one of the checkboxes and once the submit button has been pressed I need to do something based on whether the checkbox with a changed state has been checked or uncked.

Here's what I've written for now:

```
$('new_user_form').submit(function(){ 
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
              if(this.checked) 
              {
                alert("Do something!");
              } 
              else 
              {
                alert("Do something else!");
              }
         });
  });
});
```

It isn't working. Can I combine checking if the checkbox change condition with the form submit condition?

And I need help with what I'm trying to do.

**Update**

So here's what I'm using now based on the answers I got. Still not working. I would like to make sure that the script in responding to the change in state of the checkbox and also to the change in state of the checkbox and clicking the button.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
              if($(this).is(":checked")) 
              {
                alert("Checkbox checked!");
                $('#new_user_form ').submit(); 
        {
            alert("Checkbox checked and submit clicked!");
            //Do something
        });

             } 
             else 
             {
               alert("Checkbox unchecked!");
           $('#new_user_form ').submit(); 
        {
            alert("Checkbox unchecked and submit clicked!");
            //Do something else
                }); 
             }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
              if($(this).is(":checked")) 
              {
                alert("Do something!");
              $('#new_user_form ').submit(); //for submit form use in any if else as your requirement
              } 
              else 
              {
                alert("Do something else!");
              }
         });
  });
```

reference **[checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [defaultChecked](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20011210/html.html#ID-20509171) property to check whether a checkbox's state was changed

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    $('#new_user_form :checkbox').filter(function(){
        return this.checked != this.defaultChecked
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("Do something!");
        } else {
            alert("Do something else!");
        }
    });
});
```